# Is the Tiffany yellow diamond on display?

Tags: new-york-city

Is the Tiffany yellow diamond on display at the Tiffany store on 5th ave. in Manhattan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The [Tiffany Diamond](http://www.tiffany.com/Locations/FlagshipStore/NewYork.aspx) is normally on display on the Main Floor where thousands enjoy its radiant beauty.

On rare occasions, it does g[o out on loan](http://press.tiffany.com/News/NewsItem.aspx?ID=181), such as the six months it spent at the Smithsonian Institution (2007), and a period at Somerset House London (2006).

[image]